Advice for elite newbie coder TG bot trading on BASE
So I created a telegram bot.
Not sure if got the ABI right. There is no error message in command prompt.
The bot basically sends eth to the uniswap router, but I don't get the target tokens in return,.
https://basescan.org/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d
Thats the uniswap adress it sends the tokens too.
Uniswap V3 Router Contract
router_contract: Contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=router_abi)

Load the ABI for the token
def load_abi(file_path):

with open(file_path, 'r') as abi_file:

return json.load(abi_file)

Load token contract ABI
token_abi_path = 'abi/erc20.json'

token_abi = load_abi(token_abi_path)

Create the token contract
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=target_coin, abi=token_abi)

Define helper functions
def get_token_balance(address: str) -> int:

"""Get token balance of an address."""

return token_contract.functions.balanceOf(address).call()

def swap_tokens(amount_in: int, slippage: int, from_token: str, to_token: str, wallet_address: str):

"""Perform a token swap."""

Define swap details
amount_out_min = 0 # Minimum amount of tokens to receive (adjust as needed)

path = [from_token, to_token]

deadline = web3.eth.getBlock('latest')['timestamp'] + 1200 # 20 minutes from now

Build transaction
transaction = {

'from': wallet_address,

'gas': 200000, # Adjust gas limit as needed

'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),

'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_address),

}

Create swap transaction
swap_tx = router_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(

amount_out_min,

path,

wallet_address,

deadline

).buildTransaction(transaction)

Sign and send the transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(swap_tx, private_key=os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY'))

tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

return tx_hash.hex()

Something wrong with that code?
I just started btw.
MAybe I''m using the wrong or missing ABI?

Several issues here:

.1. First of all, you're not using Base chain's UniSwap v2 address. You're using the address for Ethereum Main network.
Base Uniswap v2 router address: https://basescan.org/address/0x4752ba5dbc23f44d87826276bf6fd6b1c372ad24
Ethereum Main network Uniswap v2 router address:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d
For reference: see this documentation regarding Base chain's contracts.

.2. If you were using a wrong ABI, the script should be raising an error and no transactions should have been made. It looks like that you're using swapExactETHForTokens but you mentioned that you are able to "send ETH to the router". This should not be possible because you're using the wrong address in the first place - is there something you're not telling/showing?
